# ¿Para que sirve el archivo index. index.html e index.php y que código deberia poner en index.php?

Tags: php, html

Este archivo index.php tiene el siguiente código:

```
<?php  include_once("home.html")  ?>
```

Que hacer referencia a un archivo html. Tengo miedo de estar incluyendo imágenes y otras páginas desde `home.html` y que a lo mejor han de incluirse desde `index.php`.

Por eso ¿qué es un archivo index? y ¿qué más yo debería incluir o para que otra cosa tomar en cuenta el archivo index.php?
Mi página es esta https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/

Comment: este es el código que tiene el archivo index.php <?php  include_once("home.html")  ?>

Answer (score 1):

El index es el archivo por defecto que se busca cuando no se especifica el archivo exacto en la url.

Por ejemplo en tu url solo especificas https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com y se ejecuta el archivo `index.php`. Ahora bien, también puedes especificar el archivo `index.php` y se ejecuta la misma pagina: https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/index.php.

De si utilizar `index.php` o `index.html` depende de lo que estes buscando. Si necesitas ejecutar algun codigo php, entonces utiliza index.php, de lo contrario podrias solo utilizar index.html.

Comment: en caso de querer incorporar un codigo php ¿lo haría desde index.php o desde home.html?

Comment: Sí. Todo codigo php **debe** de estar en un archivo de extension `.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Tu archivo index es el que el servidor considerará al momento de colocar la url a mostrar.

Ej:

Tu URL será http://localhost/proyecto

El servidor al leer esto, buscará internamente el archivo **index** para considerarla como pagina a mostrar, en este caso irá a:

http://localhost/proyecto/index.html o bien a http://localhost/proyecto/index.php

Esto sirve mucho para redireccionar a un usuario al inicio de session si el index considera que no hay nadie que este logueado en tu pagina desde ese navegador.

Answer (score 0):

El archivo `index.html` es el archivo que el servidor ejecuta por defecto cuando carga tu dominio. Como mencionaron los compañeros si tu dominio es `https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com`entonces al cargar la pagina tomara el index.html o index.php. Y si tienes otro archivo con un nombre distinto a index, ejemplo `login.php` entonces para acceder a el tu dominio cambiaria a algo así `https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/login.php`.

Answer (score 0):

El archivo index.{extensión} es por convención el punto de entrada de tu sitio, por lo cual es el archivo que se va a visualizar al entrar a la raiz de tu sitio web.

https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com

Si no lo tuvieras te mostraría el listado de los archivos que tuvieras en la raiz (esto depende de la configuración de tu servidor).

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo index.php puedes combinar codigo de php y de html, mientras que el el index.html no puedes poner código php, el editor de código no lo leería.

Comment: Esa es la configuración por defecto, pero claro que si puedes incluir código `php` en un archivo con extensión `.html`. Es tan simple como un par de configuraciones. Por otro lado, por _editor de código_ supongo que te refieres al interprete de scripts de php, ¿correcto?